# My Add to cart button not calling out product id

Tags: python, forms, request, return-value, wsgi

In my product details page, I have an "Add to cart" button that is expected to bring out the product through the id on the next page.

This is my view function according to tutorial:

```
        def add_to_cart(request):
        user = request.user
        product_id = request.Get.get('prod_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        Cart(user=user, product=product).save()
        return redirect("/cart")
```

In the product_details page, i have the form for the button as:

```
            <form action="/add-to-cart" class="d-inline">
                <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value={{product.id}}>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2">
                    Add to Cart
                </button>
            </form>
```

Apparently, the name stores the value of the product with the specific id. I am trying to callout the product with the id in the function so it could be added to cart but it comes with an attribute error:
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'.
My lecturer must have done something with this line:
product_id = request.Get.get('prod_id')
It worked for him in the tutorial.

please help.

Comment: Please post the full traceback and show your imports and a request

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.